# Kinematic rigidbodies push each other in unet

Tags: rigidbody, kinematic, unet

https://youtu.be/j3f44E-ExLc
I have a bunch of rigidbodies on each player, ALL set to kinematic. And this stuff happens. All the sword swinging is animation state driven, and basic back and forth and sideways motion is using Rigidbody.MovePosition. There is not supposed to be any rotation on the players' local x axis. This only seems to happen using Unet networking . Any ideas how to fix this?? Thanks!